# subprocess.Popen['vim'] in an interactive Python session yields interesting results

Tags: python, vim

Enter python shell

then type

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("vim")
```

Then the vim window opens. Try to quit vim using :q and then try typing in the interactive session.

It seems like vim does not really actually quit. It seems as if I was in vim and in the Python shell at the same time.

Why does this happen?

I know that I can avoid this by running subprocess.call or Popen.communicate() etc., I am just curious as to what exactly is happening.

It seems as if quitting vim using :q after running it in Popen still kind of keeps it running.

[image: Image of the mess generated after Popening vim and quitting]

Comment: How about showing us that mess with a screenshot?

Comment: Added image @romainl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `Popen`:

> With the default settings of `None`, the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

So both `python` and `vim` are reading from the same file *at the same time*.